# How to use Soft Hyphen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

Is there any way we can use [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) with the normal `Text` component in Jetpack Compose? I tried to just add the [soft hyphen character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ad/index.htm) `\u00AD` unicode character but no effect.